# Uncompressing a .Z file with Python

Tags: python, zlib, compression

I'm trying to uncompress a *.Z file using Python. I downloaded it via FTP (binary mode). The file successfully uncompresses with 7zip (whose "info" on the file says it's of type "Z"). The original file can be found at ftp://cddis.gsfc.nasa.gov/gps/products/1860/igr18600.sp3.Z.

I've read up on the use of the zlib module in Python and have some test code I'm using:

```
import zlib

comp_data = open('C:\Temp\igr18600.sp3.Z', 'rb').read()

print(comp_data[0:10])

uncomp_data = zlib.decompress(comp_data)
with open('c:\temp\igr18600.sp3', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(uncomp_data)
    f.close()
```

When I execute this I get the following output:

```
b'\x1f\x9d\x90#\xc6@\x91\x01#F'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    uncomp_data = zlib.decompress(comp_data)
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

zlib clearly doesn't like the header. The first couple of bytes appear to match the proper magic number sequence 0x1F9d for a compressed file (per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures).

In a pinch I can work around this by shelling out to 7zip directly. But I was hoping to find a pure Python type of answer. Despite spending most of the day googling for an answer (or this error message) I haven't had much luck. Perhaps my search skills are atrophying?

Comment: The link also mentions about `7-Zip File Format` as `37 7A BC AF 27 1C`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some years have gone by, and now there are python packages for this: `unlzw` and `unlzw3`<sup>[1]</sup>

### 1) unlzw

- GitHub: [ionelmc/python-unlzw](https://github.com/ionelmc/python-unlzw) (Last commit 2017-10)
- PyPI: [unlzw](https://pypi.org/project/unlzw/)
- Docs: [python-unlzw.readthedocs.io](https://python-unlzw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)
- Pros/Cons: The package provides a [C-extension file](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/building.html) (.so or .pyd) which makes it fast. The downside is that it has built versions only up to CPython 3.6 (as it is [not maintained](https://github.com/ionelmc/python-unlzw/issues)?), and if you install it on Windows, pip will download the `.tar.gz`, and you'll have to have a C-compiler installed to make the installation to work properly. I tried and since I have a C-compiler installed, got it working with CPython 3.8.6.

#### 1.1) Installation*

```
pip install unlzw
```

<sup>*See the note on Pros/Cons above.</sup>

#### 1.2) Example usage

```py
from unlzw import unlzw

with open('file.Z', 'rb') as fh:
    compressed_data = fh.read()
    uncompressed_data = unlzw(compressed_data)
```

### 2) unlzw3

- GitHub: [scivision/unlzw3](https://github.com/scivision/unlzw3) (Last commit 2020-07). Based on [github.com/umeat/unlzw](https://github.com/umeat/unlzw)
- PyPI: [unlzw3](https://pypi.org/project/unlzw3/)
- Pros/Cons: Pure python implementation, meaning that it will install & run on "any" platform with python, including Windows without C-compiler. It is also slower than the C-implementation (see benchmarks below).

#### 2.1) Installation

```
pip install unlzw3
```

#### 2.2) Example usage

From the [documentation](https://github.com/umeat/unlzw):

```
import unlzw3
from pathlib import Path

uncompressed_data = unlzw3.unlzw(Path('file.Z'))
```

### Appendix: Benchmarks

Using a file `igsg1450.20i.Z` downloaded from https://cddis.nasa.gov/archive/gnss/products/ionex/2020/145/.

```
unlzw
3.5 ms ± 93 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

unlzw3
166 ms ± 2.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

The benchmarks show, that for 1000 similar .Z files you would have to wait only 3.5 seconds with unlzw, but 2.8 minutes with unlzw3. For one-off conversion, the difference probably does not matter.

---

[1] All of these are actually based on the [Mark Adler's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60531/how-can-i-read-compressed-z-file-automatically-by-mathematica/60879#60879)  on mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/ncompress/ looks as though it may also be a viable candidate (only released late last year, so post-dates this answer).

Answer (score 7):

Python does not have the equivalent of Unix uncompress available in a module, which is what you'd need to decompress a .Z file.  You would either need to a) shell out to the Unix compress command, b) shell out to gzip, c) shell out to 7-zip (both gzip and 7-zip have the ability to decompress .Z files), d) modify the original uncompress code in C and link that to Python (the code is available online), or e) write your own LZW decompressor in native Python.

For d), you can find some C code I wrote to do this job [in this answer on mathematica.stackexchange.com](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60879/94).  See the `unlzw()` function.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Appreciate all your hard work on zlib. Good to hear I wasn't missing something obvious. I'll shell out to 7-zip for now and begin investigating d and e for my own edification.

Comment: @unclemeat, thanks for tackling the pure python implementation. I'll give your's a try for my application as well.