# error in decompressing a .Z file using python

Tags: python, header, compression, block, zlib

I have to decompress a .Z file which contains NDVI data in compressed state
I am using zlib to decompress it

```
str_object1 = open('Downloads/2019090120190930.Z', 'rb').read()
str_object2 = zlib.decompress(str_object1, -zlib.MAX_WBITS)
```

It is showing error

```
Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid block type
```

if I remove `-zlib.MAX_WBITS`
It is showing error

```
Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

Please help
Here is the link to the file http://www.bom.gov.au/web03/ncc/www/awap/ndvi/ndviave/month/grid/history/nat/2019090120190930.Z

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncompressing a .Z file with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921263/uncompressing-a-z-file-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a zlib file. That file was made by the ancient Unix compress command. You'll need to shell out to gzip to decompress it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32924387/1180620).