# read tar.Z datafile

Tags: python, compression, tar, tarfile

I have downloaded a data from https://archive-beta.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets?f%5Bcharacteristics%5D=time-series&p%5Boffset%5D=0&p%5Blimit%5D=10&p%5BorderBy%5D=NumHits&p%5Border%5D=desc&p%5BStatus%5D=APPROVED
but it is dataxyz.tar.Z. How do we read data in dataxyz.tar.Z with python please.

This is what it shows after following [Uncompressing a .Z file with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921263/uncompressing-a-z-file-with-python)

[output snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKKEO.png)

Comment: Thanks @stdunbar for the link. But I don't understand why the output looks funny.

Comment: Actually try [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63245360/reading-in-tar-z-file-as-pandas-data-frame-in-python-3-7-4) - looks like it's the same data.  It assumes a Unix environment.

Comment: @stdunbar thanks for pointing out. Yes, it's the same data. But I as well get 
EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file even I restarted the kernel and run.